# Cant run build: How to stop EAZFuscator from interfering?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, obfuscation, eazfuscator

Hey I uninstalled EAZFuscator from my computer but when I try to build my solution in Visual Studio, I keep getting this error which stops the build:

```
The command "if /I "Release" == "Release" Eazfuscator.NET.exe "DIRECTORY WHERE RELEASE SOLUTION IS LOCATED" --msbuild-project-path ""DIRECTORY WHERE PROJECT SOLUTION IS LOCATED"" --msbuild-project-configuration "Release" --msbuild-project-platform "x86" --msbuild-solution-path ""DIRECTORY WHERE PROJECT SOLUTION IS LOCATED"" -n --newline-flush -v 3.3" exited with code 9009.
```

How do I stop EAZFuscator from interfering with my builds? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the corresponding knowledge base article http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/kb/100024